# How to maintain a monthly leaderboard in Android app

Tags: android, android-studio

So I want to create a monthly leader-board such that whenever a user clicks on a button with some points written on them,the points automatically gets added to his database.For database I am using cloud firestore. So my question is how do I  clear the points from the 'points' field in the database at the end of every month or how do I just retrieve the points earned in that particular month?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you maintain a separate document for each month-year?
like "scores/nov_2018/user1/score"

Then you have no need to clear the points at every month, and you can get points for any month easily.

Once in a while, just delete very old month, it will delete all the documents under that month.

And write a firebase function to calculate the leader board for the month, as you know score for each user for each month now.

Comment: So I have 2 collections 1 is the users collection which contains the username , email id ,points and the other collection is 'item' which contains the item and the points associated with it.So what you are saying is for me to create another collection namely scores which will have documents related to user points for each month ?Sorry for asking such questions I am very new to how nosql things work

Comment: You can either create a new collection or put it in each user. It's not SQL, its NoSQL, its better to put the scores inside the Users document, like users/user1/scores/nov-2018

you can also create another collection of scores, but again it depends on how flexible you want it.